# PDFBox sign pdf in android application

Tags: android, groovy, pdfbox, sign

I'm currently working on an application that creates a pdf document with a signature of the user.

I managed to construct a new pdf document and fill it with data. My only problem is I don't know how to implement digital signature with pdfbox in an android application.

If you could refer me to sources or share some ideas about that I would appreaciate that!

Comment: The best would be to use the signature examples in the non-android pdfbox source code (CreateSignature / CreateVisibleSignature), and see whether these work on android.

Comment: I have looked in these examples but I didn't quite understand how do I get the user's signature and just place it inside the pdf document. If let's say I would be able to get the user's signature as a png file, will it be possible to use it as a certificate in the signature?

Comment: The image is just an image and can be anything. The signature is a byte sequence in the PDF., that is calculated based on the bytes in the PDF. I recommend you either read the PDF specification, or the source code, or have a look at a signed file with PDFDebugger.